# R: Two (apparently same) knn models return different data

Tags: r, knn

I am creating a knn classification model using the knn metod from R class package:

```
impens_test_pred <- knn(train = train_set, test = test_set, cl = train_set_labels$cleavage, k = 5)
impens_test_pred2 <- knn(train = train_set, test = test_set, cl = train_set_labels$cleavage, k = 5)
```

But when I call `ggmodels.CrossTable` for the models the confussion table is different:

```
CrossTable(x = test_set_labels$cleavage, y = impens_test_pred, prop.chisq=FALSE)
CrossTable(x = test_set_labels$cleavage, y = impens_test_pred2, prop.chisq=FALSE)

|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|test_set_labels$cleavage |     FALSE |      TRUE | Row Total | 
|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|                FALSE    |       266 |         1 |       267 | 
|                         |     0.996 |     0.004 |     0.853 | 
|                         |     0.875 |     0.111 |           | 
|                         |     0.850 |     0.003 |           | 
|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|                 TRUE    |        38 |         8 |        46 | 
|                         |     0.826 |     0.174 |     0.147 | 
|                         |     0.125 |     0.889 |           | 
|                         |     0.121 |     0.026 |           | 
|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|         Column Total    |       304 |         9 |       313 | 
|                         |     0.971 |     0.029 |           | 
|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|






|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|test_set_labels$cleavage |     FALSE |      TRUE | Row Total | 
|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|                FALSE    |       266 |         1 |       267 | 
|                         |     0.996 |     0.004 |     0.853 | 
|                         |     0.869 |     0.143 |           | 
|                         |     0.850 |     0.003 |           | 
|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|                 TRUE    |        40 |         6 |        46 | 
|                         |     0.870 |     0.130 |     0.147 | 
|                         |     0.131 |     0.857 |           | 
|                         |     0.128 |     0.019 |           | 
|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|         Column Total    |       306 |         7 |       313 | 
|                         |     0.978 |     0.022 |           | 
|-------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Why does knn returns two different models for the same data? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: did you `set.seed` ?

Comment: I used seed for creating test_set and train_set (is data from the same source), but if I am not wrong, knn should use all the data.

Comment: I believe you need to set seed before running the model.

Comment: Checked! Thank you @RanaUsman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the seed of R‘s random number generator, which is useful for creating simulations or random objects that can be reproduced.

If you try running same model with

`set.seed(123)`

It should return the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Note the following behavior when using `set.seed`:

```
set.seed(123)
sample(1:9, 1) # will always return 3
sample(1:9, 1) # will always return 8
```

So, if you want both samples to be the same, you have to set the seed twice:

```
set.seed(123)
sample(1:9, 1) # returns 3
set.seed(123)
sample(1:9, 1) # returns 3 again
```

This behavior naturally extends to functions other than `sample` that use randomization. So if you want `knn` to do the exact same thing twice, you also need to set the seed twice.